# Getting import error while trying to import StatusCanonicalCode using OpenTelemetry python library

Tags: python, open-telemetry

Importing `StatusCanonicalCode` from python opentelemetry library is giving error

```
from opentelemetry.trace.status import StatusCanonicalCode
```

Error msg:

> *** ImportError: cannot import name 'StatusCanonicalCode' from 'opentelemetry.trace.status'

The file [opentelemetry.trace.status](https://opentelemetry-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/trace.status.html) doesn't have `StatusCanonicalCode` class.

But these documentations and specifications gives this import as a valid example:

https://opentelemetry.lightstep.com/python/tracing/ -> search for `StatusCanonicalCode`

The same import is also present in [jaeger](https://opentelemetry-python-yusuket.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/opentelemetry/ext/jaeger.html) library.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

> But the documentation and specifications give this import as a valid example:

Where did spec or documentation say this import as a valid example? (Lightstep is not official, they are just vendors)

We have changed the canonical code to the status code very long back. Here is the PR which made that change https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/pull/1282.

> The same import is also present in the jaeger library

Again this link is one of the former maintainer's test documentation but not official. Here is the official documentation https://opentelemetry-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks makes sense. Will update the question to correct for the misinformation.